Using Dash with Plotly graph objects and date picker to plot and update multiple data traces in a single plot with the full data range as default
new using Dash and need to plot multiple plotly traces in a single plot using a date picker component. Looking for examples that show how to:

automatically plot the full data range as default upon loading before any date range is selected.
update the single plot frame (both traces) when the date range is selected.

Right now the date picker works, but the plot is blank until a date range is selected.  As well, when the date range is selected, the plot overlays the full data underneath the selected data.
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, html, dcc 
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# initialize the dash app as 'app'
app = Dash(__name__)

population_1=1e7+50*np.arange(61)
population_2=1e8+5*np.arange(61)**2
test_df=pd.DataFrame(data={'pop 1':population_1, 'pop 2': population_2})

test_df.index=pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2000-03-01')

# use specs parameter in make_subplots function
# to create secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# plot a scatter chart by specifying the x and y values
# Use add_trace function to specify secondary_y axes.
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=test_df.index, y=test_df['pop 1'], name="pop 1"),
    secondary_y=False)
 
# Use add_trace function and specify secondary_y axes = True.
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=test_df.index, y=test_df['pop 2'], name="pop 2"),
    secondary_y=True,)

beginning_date=test_df.index[0]
ending_date=test_df.index[-1]

# set up the app layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=
                    [
                    html.H1(children=['Test Daframe Dashboard']),
                    html.Div(children=['Population plotting with year picker']),

                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                        id='my-date-picker-range',
                        min_date_allowed=beginning_date,
                        max_date_allowed=ending_date
                    ),
                    dcc.Graph(id='population-plot',figure={}),                    
                    ] 
                    )

@app.callback(
    Output('population-plot', 'figure'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date'))

def update_output(start_date, end_date):
    print (start_date, end_date)
    
    if not start_date or not end_date:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        output_selected_df=test_df.loc[(test_df.index>=start_date)&(test_df.index<=end_date),:]
        fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=output_selected_df.index, y=output_selected_df['pop 1'], name="pop 1"),
        secondary_y=False)
 
        # Use add_trace function and specify secondary_y axes = True.
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=output_selected_df.index, y=output_selected_df['pop 2'], name="pop 2"),
            secondary_y=True,)
        return fig


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



One way to approach this is to create a function to manage the figure creation and then use it for both the initial load and the callback. You can either filter the dataframe by date outside the function or pass date parameters into the function and filter inside.
I created create_figure to demonstrate this solution. In your example, you're filtering the test_df inside the callback so the function only needs to take the dataframe as an parameter.
def create_figure(df):
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["pop 1"], name="pop 1"), secondary_y=False
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["pop 2"], name="pop 2"),
    secondary_y=True,
    )
    return fig

When you initially create the dcc.Graph, you can use the function to create the figure and pass the full dataframe to the function.
dcc.Graph(id="population-plot", figure=create_figure(test_df)),

The graph will receive the figure when layout is initialized. To prevent the callback from triggering on the page load, add prevent_initial_call=True to the callback arguments.
Finally, call create_figure(output_selected_df) inside the callback to create the filtered chart.

Here is the full code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# initialize the dash app as 'app'
app = Dash(__name__)

population_1 = 1e7 + 50 * np.arange(61)
population_2 = 1e8 + 5 * np.arange(61) ** 2
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"pop 1": population_1, "pop 2": population_2})
test_df.index = pd.date_range(start="2000-01-01", end="2000-03-01")
beginning_date = test_df.index[0]
ending_date = test_df.index[-1]


def create_figure(df):
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["pop 1"], name="pop 1"), secondary_y=False
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["pop 2"], name="pop 2"), secondary_y=True,
    )
    return fig


# set up the app layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children=["Test Dataframe Dashboard"]),
        html.Div(children=["Population plotting with year picker"]),
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id="my-date-picker-range",
            min_date_allowed=beginning_date,
            max_date_allowed=ending_date,
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="population-plot", figure=create_figure(test_df)),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("population-plot", "figure"),
    Input("my-date-picker-range", "start_date"),
    Input("my-date-picker-range", "end_date"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_output(start_date, end_date):
    print(start_date, end_date)

    if not start_date or not end_date:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        output_selected_df = test_df.loc[
            (test_df.index >= start_date) & (test_df.index <= end_date), :
        ]
        return create_figure(output_selected_df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

